# Using GROUP BY and ORDER BY on an INNER JOIN SQL query

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am using the following query to group work times and expenses for clients from three tables, one for clients, one for work times and one for expenses:

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) AS CountWork,
        COALESCE(b.totalAmount, 0) AS WorkTotal,
        COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) AS CountExpense,
        COALESCE(c.totalAmount, 0) AS ExpenseTotal
FROM    clients A
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Client, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM    work_times
            WHERE   DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-01'
            GROUP   BY Client
        ) b ON a.Client = b.Client
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Client, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM    expenses
            WHERE   DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-01'
            GROUP   BY Client
        ) c ON a.Client = c.Client
WHERE   b.Client IS NOT NULL OR
        c.Client IS NOT NULL
```

You can see the query working in a fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd61b/5).

I am trying to amend this query so that there is a row for each client for each month sorted by month and then client.  I am trying to do so with the following amended query:

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) AS CountWork,
        COALESCE(b.totalAmount, 0) AS WorkTotal,
        COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) AS CountExpense,
        COALESCE(c.totalAmount, 0) AS ExpenseTotal
FROM    clients A
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Client, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(Amount) totalAmount,
                    SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) as Month
            FROM    work_times
            GROUP   BY Month,Client
            ORDER BY Month
        ) b ON a.Client = b.Client
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Client, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(Amount) totalAmount,
                    SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) as Month
            FROM    expenses
            GROUP   BY Month,Client
            ORDER BY Month,Client
        ) c ON a.Client = c.Client
WHERE   b.Client IS NOT NULL OR
        c.Client IS NOT NULL
```

You can see the amended query in action [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd61b/4).

It's not working quite right though.  Only one row is returned for Client B even though there is a work time in January 2013 and an expense in February 2013 (so there should be 2 rows) and it appears that the rows are being ordered by Client as opposed to Month.  Could someone suggest how to amend the query to get the desired output which for the example on the second fiddle would be:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ CLIENT ║ COUNTWORK ║ WORKTOTAL ║ COUNTEXPENSE ║ EXPENSETOTAL ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ A      ║         1 ║        10 ║            1 ║           10 ║
║ B      ║         1 ║        20 ║            0 ║            0 ║
║ A      ║         1 ║        15 ║            0 ║            0 ║
║ B      ║         0 ║        0  ║            1 ║           10 ║
║ C      ║         1 ║        10 ║            0 ║            0 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: You do not need the `ORDER BY` for the two sub-selects. Just put that for the final answer.

Comment: If date is a datetime datatype, why/how do you do a substring() on it?

Comment: Your tables have redundant data, amount and date.  You need to further normalize your structure and get rid of the redundancy.  The query is too ambiguous, you're wanting to see specific data but there's no criteria in any select other than **client id is not null**. If you want to see data for a specified date range, grouped by month, then query for the date.  I'd step back and look at normalization as my first problem.

Comment: @JustAguy I'm not sure what you mean.  I am using amount to calculate the SUM and the date to group by month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something in the requirements, what you need to do is get a list of the clients and the dates and then join that to your subqueries.  So your query will be:

```
SELECT a.*,
  COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) AS CountWork,
  COALESCE(b.totalAmount, 0) AS WorkTotal,
  COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) AS CountExpense,
  COALESCE(c.totalAmount, 0) AS ExpenseTotal
FROM 
(
  select distinct c.Client, d.Month
  from clients c
  cross join
  (
    select SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) as Month
    from work_times
    union 
    select SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) as Month
    from expenses
  ) d
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT  Client, 
    COUNT(*) totalCount,
    SUM(Amount) totalAmount,
    SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) as Month
  FROM    work_times
  GROUP   BY Month,Client
  ORDER BY Month,Client
) b 
  ON a.Client = b.Client
  and a.month = b.month
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT  Client, 
    COUNT(*) totalCount,
    SUM(Amount) totalAmount,
    SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) as Month
  FROM    expenses
  GROUP   BY Month,Client
  ORDER BY Month,Client
) c 
  ON a.Client = c.Client
  and a.month = c.month
WHERE   b.Client IS NOT NULL OR
        c.Client IS NOT NULL
order by a.month, a.client
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd61b/62).

The result is:

```
| CLIENT |   MONTH | COUNTWORK | WORKTOTAL | COUNTEXPENSE | EXPENSETOTAL |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      A | 2013-01 |         1 |        10 |            1 |           10 |
|      B | 2013-01 |         1 |        20 |            0 |            0 |
|      A | 2013-02 |         1 |        15 |            0 |            0 |
|      B | 2013-02 |         0 |         0 |            1 |           20 |
|      C | 2013-02 |         1 |        10 |            0 |            0 |
```

Comment: No, you are not missing anything.  Your query returns exactly what I want.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nick happy to help, I just made a slight edit to the original query but it still returns the same result. :)

Comment: The result of your edit doesn't appear to be quite the same.  It isn't sorted by Month

Comment: @Nick All you need is to add an `ORDER BY` to the final query to get the correct ordering -- see my edit and this demo --http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd61b/62

Answer (score 0):

If you do an order by in a sub-query, it doesn't matter, because the outer query may (and may need to) re-order the results.  You want to add an order by to the outer query.

Your problem is that you are trying to order by the month and client of the B table, and also order by the month and client of the C table.  You need to define the order of B.month, B.client, and C.month and put it into an order by for the outer query.

BTW, if you only group by month in the sub-query for the C table, then client is not meaningful.  Some databases, like DB2, do not allow you to put an unaggregated field in a select if it is not in the group by.

Comment: Thanks, both the work_times and expenses rows are grouped by `Month,Client` in the fiddle.  I have amended the query in my question to reflect this.  Not sure that I can get the result I am looking for by just adding an ORDER BY to the outer query.  I have tried a few combinations and it's not working.  Part of the problem is that the expense and work time for Client B are getting combined into the same row even though they are in a different month.